# Parse a log using perl

Tags: perl

Im looking to parse a log using a perl command that I designed. So far all I would like to accomplish is pulling a specific timestamp format and retrieve the host.
the log would look like this

```
2016-05-07T09:07:04.933343+00:00 heroku[router]: status=301 bytes=680 service=2698ms connect=1ms dyno=web.2 fwd="10.29.10.29" at=info host="jamaican.com" request_id=32fc8d88-99f8-4cc2-89f9-284d059eebf8 method=GET path="/blog"
```

my command so can parse the date format I want but I cant seem to figure out how to add the host in the output. any recommendations would be great!

```
cat test.log  |
perl -lne 'print $1 if  /^([0-9]+[-]+[0-9]+[0-9]+[-]+[0-9]+[0-9]+[T]+[0-9]+[0-9]+[:]+[0-9]+[0-9]+[:]+[0-9]+[0-9])/'
```

Comment: i forgot to add the output of the perl one liner looks like this so far. 2016-05-07T09:07:42

Comment: You don't need to write single characters as `[-]`, `[T]` or `[:]`. Square brackets are meant as character classes, thus make sense if there's 2 or more chars inside.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
perl -nle'($time, $host) = /^(\S+)\s(?:\S+\s+){8}\S+="(\S+?)"/; print "$time $host"'
```

Output:

```
2016-05-07T09:07:04.933343+00:00 jamaican.com
```

- `\S` means non-space
- `\s` is space
- `(?:)` is a logical grouping that's not captured
- `{8}` are the skipped "words"
- `\S+="(\S+?)"` means: skip until `=` and capture what's between the two `"` quotes
- `($time, $host) = /.../` assigns the two captured groups to `$time` and `$host`

Answer (score 0):

You need to capture the hostname with a second capture group.

e.g. using your sample input:

```
$ cat test.log 
2016-05-07T09:07:04.933343+00:00 heroku[router]: status=301 bytes=680 service=2698ms connect=1ms dyno=web.2 fwd="10.29.10.29" at=info host="jamaican.com" request_id=32fc8d88-99f8-4cc2-89f9-284d059eebf8 method=GET path="/blog"
```

This perl one-liner extracts both timestamp and the hostname field.  I've improved the regex a little as well, using `\d` for digits, with a match count for each.

```
$ perl -lne 'print "$1 $2" if (m/(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.\d+\+\d{2}:\d{2}) ([^ ]+) /)' test.log
2016-05-07T09:07:04.933343+00:00 heroku[router]:
```

Another alternative:

```
$ perl -lne 'print "$1 $2 $3" if (m/(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.\d+\+\d{2}:\d{2}) ([^[]+)\[([^]]+)\]/)' test.log
2016-05-07T09:07:04.933343+00:00 heroku router
```

I assumed you wanted hostname of the local machine (I didn't even notice the `host="jamaican.com"` part of the log entry).  That's probably not what you wanted, so if you want the hostname that's inside the double-quotes after `host=`, then:

```
$ perl -lne 'print "$1 $2" if (m/(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.\d+\+\d{2}:\d{2}).*host="([^"]+)"/)' test.log
2016-05-07T09:07:04.933343+00:00 jamaican.com
```

or (much simpler):

```
$ perl -lne 'print "$1 $2" if (m/(^\S+).*host="([^"]+)"/)' test.log
2016-05-07T09:07:04.933343+00:00 jamaican.com
```

Or extract the timestamp, parse it with `Date::Parse` and reformat it with `Date::Format`.

```
$ perl -MDate::Parse -MDate::Format -lne \
  'if (m/(^\S+).*host="([^"]+)"/) {
     print join(" ", time2str("%Y-%m-%d %R %z",str2time($1)), $2)
   }' test.log
2016-05-07 19:07 +1000 jamaican.com
```

Note: the timestamp has been converted to local timezone (for me, that's +1000 or Australian Eastern Standard Time).  `time2str()` uses local timezone by default, but you can give it a third argument (`time2str(TEMPLATE, TIME [, ZONE])`) to make it output the time in any other zone.

```
$ perl -MDate::Parse -MDate::Format -lne   'if (m/(^\S+).*host="([^"]+)"/) {
     print join(" ", time2str("%Y-%m-%d %R %z",str2time($1),"+0"), $2)
   }' test.log
2016-05-07 09:07 +0000 jamaican.com
```

Comment: i guess the OP wants the host value.. host="jamaican.com"

Comment: ok, that's easy. (i didn't even notice the host="..." part of the log entry. i assumed he just wanted the second field)